how to start dbus service "org.freedesktop.systemd1"?
After a system upgrade (Ubuntu 22 to 23), dbus service org.freedesktop.systemd1 is broken.
$ busctl | grep systemd1
org.freedesktop.systemd1 - - -  (activatable) - -       -

$ busctl tree org.freedesktop.systemd1
Failed to introspect object / of service org.freedesktop.systemd1: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
No objects discovered.

Snapd is broken in the ripple effect.
How to start dbus service org.freedesktop.systemd1? How to reactivate it at startup?

What's the current value of $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS?

the system dbus socket lives at /run/dbus/system_bus_socket

I wasn't asking about the system bus.

org.freedesktop.systemd1 does not want to start when the disk is full.
The solution is to make space and reboot.
$ journalctl --vacuum-time=2months
$ rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*
$ reboot

